# I am trying to re-install r in my ubuntu 14.04. But I keep getting this error always I try to install r as sudo apt-get install r-base

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

```
r-base : Depends: r-base-core (>= 3.2.1-1utopic0) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: r-recommended (= 3.2.1-1utopic0) but it is not going to be installed
          Recommends: r-base-html but it is not going to be installed
 r-base-dev : Depends: r-base-core (>= 3.2.1-1utopic0) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Answer (score 0):

Run:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install r-base
```

This may fix the problem for you, otherwise check [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/142808/423973) for additional troubleshooting.